# Equation numbering does not go where it's supposed

Tags: equations, numbering

I'm running into some issues when using the `\begin{equation}` function. I know this numbers the equations automatically and puts the numbering on the RHS of the equation. Unfortunately in my case it doesn't. Here's the result of my code.

```
    \begin{equation}
        \frac{\partial \mathbf{U}}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial \mathbf{F(U)}}{\partial x}=0 \hspace{.5cm}\equiv \hspace{.5cm} \frac{\partial }{\partial t} \begin{bmatrix}
    \rho\\
    \rho u\\
    \rho E\\
    \end{bmatrix} + \frac{\partial }{\partial x}\begin{bmatrix}
    \rho\\
    \rho u^2+p\\
    \rho uH\\
    \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
    0\\
    0\\
    0\\
    \end{bmatrix}
    
    \end{equation}
```

[image: My codes results in this:]

Comment: Never ignore errors! You can't have blank lines in math mode.

Comment: Thanks! credits to @campa removing the empty lines fixed it!